# Реализация классов в Python

Tags: python, классы

возник вопрос по поводу классов, вот код:

```
class Some_Name():
    
    def f_name():
        return "Какой-нибудь текст"

x = Some_Name()
print(x.f_name())

Само собой ошибка - TypeError: info() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Что бы исправить эту ошибку достаточно в метод **f_name** добавить параметр **self**, который примет имя переменной **x**. Но! Следующий вариант кода тоже работает, и я не понимаю почему. И нигде не видел такую реализацию.

```
class Some_Name():
    
    def f_name():
        return "Какой-нибудь текст"

x = Some_Name
print(x.f_name())
```

Я просто не ставил скобки когда объявил, то что переменная **x** это класс **Some_Name**
Возможно это какой-нибудь аналог статистических классов. Если я прав, можете дать ссылку где я могу про это почитать. Если нет, то объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае с

```
x = Some_Name
print(x.f_name())
```

вы работает с методами класса напрямую, в этом можно убедиться, если посмотреть адрес метода:

```
print(Some_Name.f_name)
print(x.f_name)
```

При создании объекта от этого класса:

```
x = Some_Name()
print(x.f_name())
```

создается объект описанного вами класса, вызов методов которого иной, это уже другая функция (и у них адреса отличаются, если посмотреть так же как описано выше).

При вызове метода объект всегда подставляет первым аргументом ссылку на себя, поэтому сигнатура таких методов должна быть расширена первым аргументом. Кстати, назвать его можно как-угодно, не обязательно self. И если аргумент не был описан в методе, то возникает ошибка "... takes 0 positional arguments ..."
Именно благодаря self вы получаете доступ к данным объекта, таким образом осуществляется связка реализации метода с объектом.

Существуют еще методы классовые (привязанные к классу), у которых в качестве первого аргумент передается класс (а не объект) Для описания таких методов используют декоратор @classmethod
Эти методы ничего не знают про объект, но имеют доступ к классу, из которого вызываются.

И статические методы, сигнатура которых никак не расширяется. Для описания таких методов используют декоратор @staticmethod
Эти методы не имеют связи ни с объектом ни с классом. То есть реализацию такого метода нельзя связать с классом или объектом, который его вызывает.

Теперь по ключевым словам classmethod, staticmethod вы сможете найти много информации о реализации различных методов классов и о строение классов в питоне

Answer (score 3):

Во втором случае вы просто вызываете метод класса (а не **экземпляра** класса, как в первом случае). Это аналог статического метода как, например, в `C#`. Фактически вы вызываете метод `Some_Name.f_name()`.